# Typescript definition for union-type js

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

Would like to seek help writing d.ts file for https://github.com/paldepind/union-type

With the union type below,

```
let Maybe = Type({
    Nothing: []
    , Just: [Number]
})
```

I would love to see compiler error in case `Maybe.Nothing()` is mistyped as `Maybe.None()`

I tried to capture the keys from the object literal, but the compiler still fails to recognize `Nothing` and `Just` in the resulting type `Maybe`.

```
interface Obj {
    prototype: any
    case: (x: {[index: string]: (...args) => any}) => any
    caseOn: (x: {[index: string]: (...args) => any}) => any
}
interface Union<T> {
    (desc: T): T & Obj
}
var Type: Union<{[key: string]: any}>
export = Type
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for are **Index Type**, see the [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) section of the handbook for more explanation on how they work.
I've also been making a declaration file for paldepind/union-type, but it's incomplete :

```
declare module 'union-type' {
  type Constructors =
    | StringConstructor
    | NumberConstructor
    | ArrayConstructor
    | BooleanConstructor
    | ObjectConstructor
    | FunctionConstructor

  export default function Type<
    T extends {
      [k: string]: (Constructors | ((arg?: any) => boolean | Constructors))[]
    },
    K extends keyof T
  >(
    desc: T
  ): {
    // case(cases: { [k in K]: (...args: any[]) => void }, obj: any): void
    [k in K]: (...args: any[]) => any
  }
}
```

I'm also trying to find a workaround that library in TS...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Maybe implementation here is one I wrote once upon a time

```
/**
 * A Maybe implementation
 * that is JavaScript first
 * i.e. simple typed abstraction over null/undefined
 */
export class Maybe<T>{
    private _value: T;
    /** Based on value it will be Some or None */
    constructor(value: T) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    /** Shorthand for constructor */
    static Some<T>(value: T): Maybe<T> {
        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            throw new Error('value for some cannot be null or undefied');
        }
        return new Maybe(value);
    };
    static None<T>(): Maybe<T> {
        return new Maybe(null);
    };
    get value(): T {
        return this._value;
    }
    get isSome() {
        return this._value !== null && this._value !== undefined;
    }
    get isNone() {
        return !this.isSome;
    }
    map<U>(mapper: (now: T) => U): Maybe<U> {
        if (this.isSome) {
            return new Maybe(mapper(this._value));
        }
        else {
            return new Maybe(null);
        }
    }
}
```

That said, I find it pretty useless, much simpler to be just aware of `null/undefined` and use `valid` property on your objects (more https://medium.com/@basarat/null-vs-undefined-in-typescript-land-dc0c7a5f240a)

## More

That all said typescript is going to get first class *nullability* support https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140 and you will be able to do `number | null | undefined` and you would not be allowed to assign `null` to a number i.e. `let foo:number = null; // Error foo is not nullable`

Comment: Appreciate @basarat for your quick reply. But I was quoting the Maybe type just as an example, not looking for an implementation. I want to seek help writing the type definition for https://github.com/paldepind/union-type, so that I can have the tsc compiler highlight typo errors for me. Currently I have to use `any`, which is as good as no typing. Could you help me on that?